# How to test page content within an array of Capybara elements?

Tags: capybara

I'm using Cucumber, Capybara, and RSpec. Let's say I have a list of things on a page:

```
<ul>
  <li><span class="title">Thing 1</span><span class="description">Desc 1</span></li>
  <li><span class="title">Thing 2</span><span class="description">Desc 2</span></li>
  <li><span class="title">Thing 3</span><span class="description">Desc 3</span></li>
</ul>
```

I can get all of those list items with:

```
all('li').count.should == 3
```

Now I want to test that the content is correct for every item. The order is important. I've tried a few different things that all felt really messy, or resulted in errors. For example:

```
things = Thing.all
all('li').each_with_index do |element, index|
  within element do
    page.should have_content things[index].title
    page.should have_content things[index].description
  end
end

undefined method `element' for #<Cucumber::Rails::World:0x007fe1b62f8308>
```

What is the best way to test the content of each item?

Comment: Which assertion library are you using?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could collect the text of each li as an array:

```
all('li span.title').map(&:text)
```

Then you could compare that array to your expected content. Assuming `things` was enumerable, you could do:

```
things = Thing.all
expected_content = things.map(&title)
actual_content = all('li span.title').map(&:text)

# For an order dependent test:
expect(actual_content).to eq(expected_content)

# For an order independent test:
expect(actual_content).to match_array(expected_content)
```

Given there are multiple parts to check, it might be easier to loop through each element rather than repeating the above per part:

```
things = Thing.all
all('li').zip(things).each do |li, thing|
  expect(li.find('span.title').text).to eq(thing.title)
  expect(li.find('span.description').text).to eq(thing.description)
end
```

Comment: Your second example is still order dependent )

Comment: Thanks, that's a good start. However, based on your answer, I realize now that my example was inadequate...I'll update my question, but lets say the content is more complicated than `text == content`. For example, the elements will contain other elements, so testing a substring using something like `has_content` may be necessary.

Comment: Thanks @AndreyBotalov, I corrected the copy and paste errror.

Comment: @Andrew, I have updated the answer to reflect the updates to the question.

Comment: Ah! I think this is the first time I've ever understood the purpose of `zip`. Thanks!